# Why do Gmail addresses without dot appear in my contacts?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

Some weeks ago I found out that some of my contacts in Gmail have two addresses, one with dot and one without a dot in their name. For example `johndoe@gmail.com` and `john.doe@gmail.com`.

First I thought my friends switched from dotted to non-dotted but now I realized, they never used the non-dotted address. The address just has been added automatically to *all* of my contacts with Gmail-addresses.

Does anyone know why? I don't like the idea of Google editing *my* contacts without asking me.

Clarification: I know that Gmail does not recognise dots in addresses. I know that the two addresses above are equal for Gmail. My question is about my contacts: *Who edited them?* I never added the addresses without dots but now they are there.

Comment: Just found out that this happened before: In some contacts (especially people living in Germany) I have two addresses: one with `googlemail.com` and another with `gmail.com`. The `googlemail.com` address is labelled with `Obsolte`, and I'm sure I never used this word to for naming an address. So, looks like Gmail edits contacts for me, but sorry Google, touching my contacts was a very bad idea. @others: please don't explain to me, why googlemail addresses are obsolte. I know it.

Comment: I’d say that the two situations are a bit different: the Googlemail to Gmail transition is somehow “legitimate”, while the dot-in-the-middle one not so much. At least in my opinion.

Comment: Both changes have been done in _my_ contacts. Even if the data is stored on Google's servers, I want to be the only one who can edit it.

Comment: I know, and you are right, but the phasing from Googlemail to Gmail has nothing to do with you or the respective user — is like your Facebook URL would change from `www.facebook.com/your_nickname` to `www.fb.com/your_nickname`. As in, they are not editing the contact, but transitioning _their_ part. While the change from `youruser` to `your.user` is touching/editing _your_ (well, the user’s) part.

Comment: I had the same question as you, but I didn't know that gmail addresses are *dot invariants*... Happy to hear it from you.

Comment: Is there any technical reason behind ignoring the dots? It seems to be a rather odd decision to me.

Comment: I don't think this is a technical decision.